# Allow traffic from one VLAN to another via WAN access

Tags: vlan, pfsense, web-hosting

The most concise way to ask is: I just learned that, even using a public URL to a website hosted on my LAN does not work when visiting it from my other VLAN, but is the fpSense Reflection setting of NAT + Proxy the best way to allow it?

My setup is:

Internet > pfSense > TP-Link TL-SG1016PE switch > Ubuntu haproxy (reverse proxy)

In pfSense and on the switch, I created a VLAN for my downstairs neighbour with the idea of isolating our devices. This works great, including broadcasting two wireless SSID's, one for each LAN/subnet.

I also have some websites hosted on my own LAN that are exposed to the Internet. However, I just discovered that my downstairs neighbour can't reach my websites, even when using a public link.

In pfSense, I remember turning on Reflection (System > Advanced > Firewall & NAT > Network Address Translation) so that I could reach my websites and services from my LAN using a public link, but I never fully understood whether I should set it to *Pure NAT* or *NAT + Proxy*. Lo and behold, changing to NAT + Proxy allows my neighbour to access my websites. So, my question is: Is this good practice? Should I have done it differently, given that my goals are:

1. Device isolation between my two LANs.
2. Access to the services that are on my LAN, from my LAN, but using public links.
3. Access to the services on my LAN, from the other VLAN, using public links.